# Django templates - dynamically create variables from dict

Tags: python, django

In one template I'm trying to spawn groups of similiar elements.
In short, I have some lines similiar to this:

> {% include "some/path.html" with key1=value1 key2=value2 %}
>
> {% include "some/path.html" with key2=value3 key4=value4 %}

and so on...

And variables passed to `with` statement are different. Rest variables, not passed to `with` statement have default values described in "some/path.html" template.

My idea was to pass some dict (or list) to template and template would pass arguments to `with` statement based on dict.
For example i would have dict: `{0: {key1: value1, key2: value2}, 1: {key2: value3, key4: value4}}`
and this dict would be evaulated to arguments passed to `with` statement.

How can I achieve it? Or if it's bad solution, what can I do instead?

I would love to get some help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Into a template, you can access datas into dicts/objects/whatether with the '.'.

Try to pass the dict into your context like this in the view :

```
context['my_dict'] = {0: {key1: value1, key2: value2}, 1: {key2: value3, key4: value4}}
```

Then you can access it like this in your template :

```
{% include "some/path.html" with key1=my_dict.0.key1 key2=my_dict.0.key2 %}

{% include "some/path.html" with key2=my_dict.1.key2 key4=my_dict.1.key4 %}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. 
I would like to avoid hardcoding as much as possible. 
I can imagine i will have 15 includes of same file. Now i want to introduce new variable to 16th file. So i will just add line keyX=my_dict.16.keyX, and i don't want to add this by myself in template file, i'd like to add this in my python view. 
I'd like to be able to do "{% include "x.html" with {% for k, v in dict.items %}k=v{% endfor %} %}, but this doesn't work. I hope you get me :)

Answer (score 0):

I scratched my head a lot and came up with this!
Gonna post it, so maybe it will be useful.
in `/yoursite/templatetags/yourcustomtag.py`
type

```
from django import template
import sys
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def yourTag(context):
    for k, v in your_dict_in_this_context:
        context[k] = v
    return
```

And in your templates call

```
{% load yourcustomtag %}
{% yourTag %}
```

and you have loaded values from dict to your context! Yay!